# Precise word to describe "falling short of greatness" or "eluded by greatness"

Tags: single-word-requests

I would like to narrow down what options we have in English to the concept of being very close to seizing greatness for oneself but falling short. A ready example that comes to mind is the [Alexander Romance](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Alexander_Romance), where this feeling/plot sequence appears to be a frequent motif. Here's the following sentence to work with:

> Alexander and his forces rested near the Fountain of Youth, though
> only Alexander's cook drank the water while Alexander only heard of
> the water's miraculous effects after it was too late to turn back.
> Alexander came very near greatness, but it eluded him, a rather ______
> fate.

I think "tragic" or "ironic" would be appropriate here but they are a bit too broad/vague. If at all possible, I want a word that places emphasis on the *upside* potential that was forsaken or lost, not so much that the result was less than ideal or sad.

Comment: I can think of a lot of words that might fit, but you need to be clearer what precisely you want to communicate. Is it a disappointment for the person involved? Is it disappointing or underwhelming for others? Is it a neutral case of underachievement like someone scoring slightly worse in an exam they don't care about? Is it sad? Does it inspire sympathy? Does it act as a warning? Is it a symbol of the inevitable tragedy/futility/tragi-comedy/indifference/uncaringness of human life which always ends in failure and death?

Comment: I would like the emphasis to be on coming close to greatness but not achieving it, in the example it could be argued that it was hidden from him or that he was not perceptive enough, though ideally the answer would be robust to the source of the inhibiting turn of events or flaws of the person. The focus is on being on the cusp of greatness but not obtaining it.

Comment: It's ironic that his name is Alexander the Great.

Comment: You can say [***greatness / fame / wealth eluded him***](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=greatness+eluded+him%2Cfame+eluded+him%2Cwealth+eluded+him&year_start=1919&year_end=2019&corpus=en-2019&smoothing=3), but it's [not idiomatic](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=eluded+by+greatness%2Celuded+by+fame%2Celuded+by+wealth&year_start=1919&year_end=2019&corpus=en-2019&smoothing=3) to say he was eluded ***by*** some desirable goal.

Answer (score 1):

If we keep it simple:

> Alexander came very near greatness, but it eluded him, a rather *disheartening/disappointing* fate.

MW: **disheartening**: causing the loss of hope, enthusiasm, or courage

**disappointing**: causing loss of spirit or morale; failing to meet expectations.

Answer (score 0):

Alexander missed a great opportunity that will not happen again. A rather [**pathetic**](https://www.vocabulary.com/dictionary/pathetic) fate.

Examples :

> What a pathetic fate for the man who recently held the destiny of the
> world in his hands !
>
> I sometimes doubt whether there is someone else
> out there who share my pathetic fate.

Comment: Pathetic seems to be far more extreme than just missing greatness.